# Google Translate not showing Language Options

Tags: google-translate

I have put Google translate code on my site, but it's not showing Language option in select field:

[image]

And the code is:

```
<div id="google_translate_element"></div><script type="text/javascript"> 
 function googleTranslateElementInit() {
   new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', layout: 
   google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.HORIZONTAL, autoDisplay: false},      
   'google_translate_element');
 }
</script><script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

Comment: Having the exact same issue - though only on a tiny minority of browsers (specific versions of Firefox in my case).

Answer (score 0):

Re : google.Translate.ElementInit() callback .. **autoDisplay: True** or deleted should render the language options. Note that the option (language trigger value and name) are not rendered immediately after the this callback .. which is irritating if you want to switch language on a navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage result.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code i use:

```
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function googleTranslateElementInit() {
        new google.translate.TranslateElement({
            pageLanguage: 'en',
            autoDisplay:true,
            defaultLanguage: 'en',
        }, 'google_translate_element');
    }
</script>
```